# How to keep client connected to server in c# socket?

Tags: c#, sockets

I want my server to keep listening the the same client. It listen the client only one time. How can i keep reading the data sent from client side.

```
           sk = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
            sk.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5000));
            sk.Listen(-1);

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {

                    Socket client = sk.Accept();
                    NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(client);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            int read = ns.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            if (read <= 0)
                                break;
                            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                        }
                    }
                    MemoryStream msi = new MemoryStream(buffer);
                    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(msi);

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
```

Comment: You should use a while, just as you have, but wrap the socket read part. It's not really clear what you want to do. You break out of the read loop when you don't receive any data, but what kind of protocol do you use, or intend to use, to distinguish what the client is sending to the server?

Comment: client just keep sending encoded frames. But server receive only once. It must keep receiving data  in loop . You can ignore whats going in read part

Comment: If it keeps sending encoded frames, how do you know what size the frames are?

Comment: Also, you overwrite the same part of the buffer on each write, and only save the last few received bytes. This is not a particularly good pattern for network code, since you will just drop the data packets that were received at the start.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you explain it a little bit further? Do you want to get more than 1 image from the same client? you only get one packet from the client? you want to have multi-clients at the same time?

Comment: One of the first problems I see is that you're catching all `Exception`s but doing nothing about them. This may be masking the problem, which I suspect is with your `Socket client = sk.Accept();` line. You should not be accepting the socket multiple times as you are. Accept once outside the main `while` loop. In addition, you are creating a new `NetworkStream` object each time you read, which is also unnecessary. Put this line outside the main loop as well.

Comment: Thanks guys problem is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a way to this problem

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serverSocket = new TcpListener(9361);
        clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        Thread listen = new Thread(listenClients);
        listen.Start();

    }
//this will keep listening the clients
    public void listenClients()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        serverSocket.Start();
        counter = 0;
        while ((true))
        {
            counter += 1;
            clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

            Thread thread = new Thread(
                () => readClient(clientSocket));
            thread.Start();
        }
    }

    public  void broadcast(Image bmp)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    }  //en
 //keep reading the client data
    private void readClient(TcpClient inClientSocket)
    {

        byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[65536];
        string dataFromClient = null;
        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {
                NetworkStream networkStream = inClientSocket.GetStream();
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytesFrom);
                Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
                broadcast(returnImage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        } //end while
    } //end readClint
```

Comment: Instead of trying to open networkStream through while loop, use while (!stream.DataAvailable); code and create networkStream in upper level.